# How can I delete a blob using azure logic apps

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps

This is the set up for my creation of the blobs.
Through postman I can post a image and some metadata
The file name just uses ticks(utcNow)
The blob image is stored in my storage account

[image]

[image]

[image]

and then after this I return 200 and the body.

This works for the creation.

To delete I have tried specifying the path of the blob in the storage account by placing it in the relative path in the HTTP request, and then using the delete blob action however I keep on receiving this error

```
The server did not receive a response from an upstream server. Request tracking id 08584997266207926527284821917CU28
```

Comment: So if your errors is in the deletion, do you. It think it would be smart to show us that flow and not this one? Show us the action and the error as you see it.

Comment: Provide 2 logic apps full design, then one can try

Answer (score 0):

> How can I delete a blob using azure logic apps

The below approach worked for me:

**`1st Logic App Design:`**

Creating blob and sending the blob path to 2nd logic app:

[image]

**`2nd Logic App Design:`**

Deleting blob using path, which i got from 1st logic app:

[image]

**`Output:`**

[image]

[image]

After calling 1st Logic app it creates a new blob ,then 1st logic app calls 2nd one and deletes the blob:

[image]